# Login security in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

I'm new to MVC and i'm looking for a way to be able to block a user out if they exceed 3 login failures into my web application.

Is there any relevant methods or action filters that anyone can point me in the direction of to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to record the failed attempts somewhere. I typically record the failed attempt with a combination of their IP and the account name they attempted. Then depending how frequently consecutive failures are logged, start to auto reject future attempts for a time frame, and gradually increase the time frame with each further failure. I don't like the pattern of locking the account just because of the failed attempts, and I don't want failed attempts from a malicious user to affect legitimate users (hence the IP). But I ended up implementing all this manually as I didn't see anything that supported it naively the way I wanted when I was writing it.

That being said, your question isn't about specific code and doesn't include coding example. So I doubt you'll get what you're looking for this way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm really looking for peoples viewpoint on how they have tackled this problem previously.

Comment: I understand what you're looking for, I'm just pointing out that questions on StackOverflow are intended to be specific programming questions with examples, errors, or things of that nature. So you're question will likely be closed as being 'off-topic' or too open ended since it's just looking for opinions or things of that nature.